# How to include a custom filter in a Keras based CNN?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I am working on a fuzzy convolution filter for CNNs. I have the function ready - it takes in the 2D input matrix and the 2D kernel/weight matrix. The function outputs the convolved feature or the activation map.

Now, I want to use Keras to build the rest of the CNN that will have the standard 2D convolution filters too.

Is there any way I can insert my custom filter into the Keras model in such a way that the kernel matrix is updated by the built in libraries of the Keras backend? Alternatively is there any library that I can use to update the kernel with every iteration?

Answer (score 13):

Suppose we want to apply a `3x3` **custom filter** onto an `6x6` **image**.

[image]

---

**Necessary import**

```py
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
from keras import Input, layers
from keras.models import Model
```

**Definition of the *custom filter***

[image]

```py
# custom filter
def my_filter(shape, dtype=None):

    f = np.array([
            [[[1]], [[0]], [[-1]]],
            [[[1]], [[0]], [[-1]]],
            [[[1]], [[0]], [[-1]]]
        ])
    assert f.shape == shape
    return K.variable(f, dtype='float32')
```

**Dummy example input image** (it is `1` channel image. So dimension will be `6x6x1` . Here, pixel values are random integer. Generally pixel values should be `0 to 255` or `0.0 to 1.0`.)

```py
input_mat = np.array([
    [ [4], [9], [2], [5], [8], [3] ],
    [ [3], [6], [2], [4], [0], [3] ],
    [ [2], [4], [5], [4], [5], [2] ],
    [ [5], [6], [5], [4], [7], [8] ],
    [ [5], [7], [7], [9], [2], [1] ],
    [ [5], [8], [5], [3], [8], [4] ]
])

# we need to give the batch size. 
# here we will just add a dimension at the beginning which makes batch size=1
input_mat = input_mat.reshape((1, 6, 6, 1))
```

**Dummy conv model** where we will use our custom filter

```py
def build_model():
    input_tensor = Input(shape=(6,6,1))

    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=1, 
                      kernel_size = 3,
                      kernel_initializer=my_filter,
                      strides=2, 
                      padding='valid') (input_tensor)

    model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=x)
    return model
```

**Testing**

```py
model = build_model()
out = model.predict(input_mat)
print(out)
```

**Output**

```
[[[[ 0.]
   [-4.]]

  [[-5.]
   [ 3.]]]]
```

---

Comment: Thanks for this. However I'm wondering if this will remain "frozen" when training a network which contains this filter in one layer. For example, one convolutional layer has the fixed filters (so no weights to be learned), then the remaining layers require coefficients to be learned. Does this example work in this case?

Comment: The custom filter will be **trainable** by default. But if you use  `layers.Conv2D(..., kernel_initializer=my_filter, trainable=False)` then it will be **frozen**. So, you can make it trainable or non-trainable whatever you want.

Comment: here is an example - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12hLFZKAf-4p-mkVpzWz78dz5PHRPPgsz

Comment: How can you define a wide variety of filters? So normally many filters and their combinations can be defined in conv2d, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own layer class. You can find a good documentation about it [here](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/). Furthermore, you can start by using the code of the `Conv2D` [class](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L359). Now, you only have to change the way how the kernel is initially created. This way, your filters will be updated according to the backpropagation. If you do not want your custom filter to change you must create a new variable (which only contains your filter), calculate the convolution using `K.conv(...)` and concatenate this result with the usual output.

Comment: Can you give a small example of this ("If you do not want your custom filter to change you must create a new variable (which only contains your filter), calculate the convolution using K.conv(...) and concatenate this result with the usual output."), using sin and cos as a rotation filter, please? That would not require any updates and would help consolidate the idea. Thank you.

Comment: @Moondra did you figure this out?

Comment: @enjal No, I am actually searching again for an answer.