# How to implement custom filters when training a CNN model?

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I am making a CNN model and want to process the images by applying a custom filter on them before feeding them in to the original CNN. Any idea how to implement this ?
I have tried the approach mentioned in the following link but its throwing an 'assertion error'!
[How to include a custom filter in a Keras based CNN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930312/how-to-include-a-custom-filter-in-a-keras-based-cnn)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem of `Assertion Error` usually occurs when the number of output dimensions from the processing do not match with the number of input dimensions of your original CNN.

Make sure that the dimensions of the output produced in the link mentioned is same as dimensions of your original CNN.

It should work then! Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am not able to figure out where the dimensions are incorrect. Following is my code. `def my_filter(shape, dtype=None):

    f = np.array([
            [[[-1]], [[2]], [[-2]], [[2]], [[-1]]],
            [[[2]], [[-6]], [[8]], [[-6]], [[2]]],
            [[[-2]], [[8]], [[-12]],[[8]], [[-2]]],
            [[[2]], [[-6]], [[8]],[[-6]], [[2]]],
            [[[-1]], [[2]], [[-2]],[[2]], [[-1]]],
        ])
    assert f.shape == shape
    return K.variable(f, dtype='float32') def build_model():
    input_tensor = Input(shape=(256,256,3))`

Comment: `model = layers.Conv2D(filters=1, 
                      kernel_size = 5,
                      kernel_initializer=my_filter,
                      strides=2,
                      padding='same') (input_tensor)

    return model `

Comment: Can you also provide the error and where it shows the error?

Comment: The error is in the model definition. model = layers.Conv2D(filters=1, 
                      kernel_size = 5,
                      kernel_initializer=my_filter,
                      strides=2,
                      padding='valid') (input_tensor)

Comment: It's throwing the error here because `f.shape` is not equal to `shape` passed as a parameter to `my_filter` function. You need to make those 2 shapes same or else it won't work.

Comment: how do I resolve that error then? I have attached the screenshots of the code in the updated question. please have a look

Comment: Try removing `assert f.shape == shape` line from the code and see what happens

Comment: that error is resolved. thanks! But I am running into a different error now : InvalidArgumentError: Depth of output (1) is not a multiple of the number of groups (3) for '{{node conv2d_39/convolution}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](input_1, conv2d_39/convolution/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,256,256,3], [5,5,1,1].

Comment: This error dissapers when I change the input shape of the first layer to (256,256,1) instead of (256,256,3) but I am working with images having 3 channels so how do I tackle this?