# Creating custom Conv2D layer in Keras with several hard-coded filters?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create **one** custom `Conv2D` layer with **several** (up to thousands) **different** **hard-coded** filters.

After doing some research, I know that I could either:

1. use the `kerel_initializer` parameter in `Conv2D` (as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930312/how-to-include-a-custom-filter-in-a-keras-based-cnn))
2. write my own `Conv2D` layer

My question is, it seems like you could only hard-code one filter using `kernel-initializer`? So I would have to add several `Conv2D` layers with `filter=1` if I used the first approach.

But then aside from custom filters and being non-trainable, I would want everything else to work exactly as another `Conv2D` layer, so it seems kind of lame to just implement another one.

Could this be implemented in any simple approach? Or do I have no choice but implement my own `Conv2D`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think that you can hard-code only one filter? You can write a custom kernel initializer with an output shape of your choice (arbitrary number of filters). You will need to write a generator for your filters and make a call to it in the kernel initializer.

Comment: @IvanK. I found that I misunderstood the api, and you sure could hard-code multiple filters using kernel_initializer. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

[tf.nn.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) takes filters as an input argument for the layer:

```
tf.nn.conv2d(
    input, filters, strides, padding, data_format='NHWC', dilations=None,
    name=None
)
```