# Keras define custom multiple filters in conv2d

Tags: python, keras, filter, deep-learning, convolution

It is said that the filter definition for conv2d is random in Keras (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/16466/43571). In another post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57671305/2590509), it is explained that we can assign custom filter. My  question is, how we can define multiple type/forms of filters manually/customly in conv2d. I want to use sobel, canny, prewit and roberts edge detectors as filters (https://globaljournals.org/GJCST_Volume12/5-Study-and-Comparison-of-Different-Edge.pdf )

Comment: you want to apply these filters where?

Comment: I want to define these filters by custom. At the end, I want to use them like self attention layer. may be I should define each filter as multiheaded.

Answer (score 0):

According to the posts that you mentioned here, you have two options:

1. Either implement a specific function which must return a tensor, using `K.()`.
2. You subclass the `Layer` class and then implement a custom layer to perform the type of convolution you want.

However, the real question in this case is : why would you like to achieve this? In essence, not only in Keras but in all deep-learning frameworks are those filters randomly initialised, and they are able on their own to learn those features mentioned by you. This is why we allow trainable filters, since they can learn on their own what we, as programmers, would hard-code and manually feed those filters.

In my opinion if you do need(?) and want to implement those filters separately, go with solution 1, create a class with static methods where each method represents a custom filter.

However, **I cannot stress how strongly I recommend to avoid that**; this is why we do machine learning and deep learning, to avoid hardcoding aspects and let the models learn what they need on their own, many times better than what we would do with a much greater effort.